# Applescript - Recursively step through directories

Tags: applescript, automator, finder

I have found similar solutions like this:

```
property theOpenFile : missing value

tell application "Finder" to set theSel to selection
if theSel is not {} then
    set pathToYourTextFile to (path to desktop folder as string) & "SampleTextFile2.txt"
    set theOpenFile to open for access file (pathToYourTextFile as string) with write permission
    repeat with aItem in theSel
        tell application "Finder" to class of aItem is folder
        if the result then my getFilesIn(aItem) -- aItem is a folder
    end repeat
    close access theOpenFile
end if

on getFilesIn(thisFolder)
    tell application "Finder" to set theseFiles to files of thisFolder as alias list
    repeat with thisFile in theseFiles
        set f to thisFile as string
        set pathLength to length of f
        if pathLength > 255 then my writeToFile(f)
    end repeat
    tell application "Finder" to set theseSubFolders to folders of thisFolder
    repeat with tSubF in theseSubFolders
        my getFilesIn(tSubF) -- call this handler (recursively through this folder)
    end repeat
end getFilesIn

on writeToFile(t)
    write (t & return) to theOpenFile starting at eof
end writeToFile
```

They all work in with a file reference in alias format. As I understand I cannot change the filename of the original in this case, or delete it, etc. and thats what I want to do.

Am I right ? If yes what else can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can rename and delete files, the `Finder` can handle `alias` specifiers

```
repeat with thisFile in (get theseFiles) -- you need get to capture the reference list
    set f to thisFile as string
    set pathLength to length of f
    if pathLength > 255 then my writeToFile(f)
    tell application "Finder" to set name of thisFile to "foo.txt"
    -- or 
    tell application "Finder" to delete thisFile
end repeat
```

or rather than an `alias` you can use Finder `file` specifiers

```
repeat with thisFile in (get theseFiles)
    set f to thisFile as string
    set pathLength to length of f
    if pathLength > 255 then my writeToFile(f)
    tell application "Finder" to set name of file f to "foo.txt"
    -- or 
    tell application "Finder" to delete file f
end repeat
```